# Android Facebook Login : How to check login using LoginManager without having LoginButton in XML

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have done facebook login check in my android app using LoginButton, but I want to check using LoginManager. How can I modify my code to work that way?

```
   LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    //Login Callback registration
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in LoginResult on success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Login success - process to Post
            if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                String description = "description";
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("title")
                        .setContentDescription(description)
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://google.com"))
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://google.com"))
                        .build();

                shareDialog.show(linkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in LoginResult on cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in LoginResult on error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Also I want to open Facebook login dialog if user is not logged in before opening by Share dialog. The Login dialog should be same as Share Dialog (in a popup). How to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: what you need to check ? weather user has logged or not ???

Comment: Yes, check if user is logged in. If No, show login dialog. If already login, then directly show share dialog as I am showing now.

Comment: I was previously checking login on click on LoginButton. But now I want to remove LoginButton and do it using LoginManager. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check, if user logged, by calling the method `Loginmanger`.[logInWithReadPermissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/#logInWithReadPermissions), to manually start login process, without button. You can do it in the `onCreate` method. If user are logged, it immediately call `onSuccess` callback method, where you can call your `shareDialog`. If user are not logged, it will show login screen. And if it was successful (i.e user logged), `onSuccess` method will be called;

Actually, you can remove from your code all `login button` mentions, and add one line to the end:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, "user_friends"); //Log in to FB
```

You can use also use WritePermissions. You can read about required permissions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference).

Here's your code, but wrapped as login method, without any login button instances. You can call it anywhere, when you need to check, if user is logged.

```
public void checkLogin() {
    //Login Callback registration
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in LoginResult on success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Login success - process to Post
            if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                String description = "description";
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("title")
                        .setContentDescription(description)
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://google.com"))
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://google.com"))
                        .build();

                shareDialog.show(linkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in LoginResult on cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in LoginResult on error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, "user_friends"); //Log in to FB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the User Profile for that , Try this ,

```
    Profile dd = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getCurrentProfile();
    if(dd != null)
    {
        //user has logged
    }
    else
    {
        //not logged
    }
```

You can re-initiate login without LoginButton as follows ,

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(<required permissions>));
```

Also you need to implement callback for above request

Comment: Ok, how do I initiate facbook login if user is not logged in? Previously it was initiated on click of LoginButton in XML. I have removed the LoginButton now from XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProfileTracker in a similar way to track changes in the current profile:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(
                Profile oldProfile,
                Profile currentProfile) {
            // here if session exist
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}
```

Source from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#get_current